# XPages how to get the id of the link when clicked in xp:this.script?

Tags: javascript, xpages

How can I get the ID of the link when I click it in the xp:this.script ?

$(this).attr('id') will return an undefined cause this probably refers to the script not the xp:link

Comment: $(this).getParent().attr("id")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
$(this).getParent().attr("id")
```

Answer (score 0):

the answer from Thomas helped me:
$(this).getParent().attr("id")